# Boundary of a ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that the open ball $B(0,1) = \{(x,y): x^2 +y^2 < 1\}$ has the boundary $x^2+y^2=1$. I understand that the boundary is the closure of the ball minus the interior. So, if i can show that the closure of the ball is less than or equal to one, then i would essentially be done, but im not sure how to do this. I know the closure contains the limit points of the set, but im not sure how to use this to help me prove what the closure of the ball is.

Answer (score 1):

If you show that some point $z\notin A$ is a limit point, then it must be a boundary point since each neighborhood contains a point in $A$ and also $z\notin A$ itself. On the other hand, if $z$ is a boundary point then each neighborhood intersects $A$, thus $A-\{z\}$, so it is a limit point. That means that outside of $A$ the limit points and the boundary point coincide.

Take $z=(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$ and $\epsilon>0$. For a $\lambda>1-\epsilon$, show that $d(z,\lambda z)=||z-\lambda z||<\epsilon$ and $d(0,\lambda z)=||\lambda z||<1$. Then you know that $\lambda z\in B_\epsilon(z)\cap B_1(0)$, and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $z$ is a limit point of the open ball.

What remains is to prove that each $z$ with $||z||>0$ is not a limit point, i.e. there is an $\epsilon$ such that $B_\epsilon(z)$ is disjoint from the ball.

Answer (score 0):

Any point $(x, y)$ in the set $\{(x, y) \ | \ x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ is a limit point of $B(0, 1)$ since any open ball around $(x, y)$ contains points in $B(0, 1)$ not equal to $(x, y)$. Remember that a closure of a set $A$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points. What are the other limit points of $B(0, 1)$? After you figure this out and prove it, you'll find that the closure is $\{(x, y) \ | \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, and your proof is straightforward from this point.